# Parsing XML file from URL into Array

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to parse a url that contains a xml file. I have tried many methods but I cannot get my head around it.
Here is the xml file:

```
<xml>
<jobs>
<id>6</id>
<type>0</type>
<user_id>9</user_id>
<name>Steve Jobs</name>
<profilepic>
http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b9/Steve_Jobs_Headshot_2010-     CROP.jpg/1024px-Steve_Jobs_Headshot_2010-CROP.jpg
</profilepic>
<bg>
http://9to5mac.files.wordpress.com/2014/08/yosemite-4.jpg
</bg>
<em>1</em>
<facebook>stevejobs</facebook>
<twitter>LegendSteveJobs</twitter>
<phone/>
<email/>
</jobs>
</xml>
```

It would be best if I could extract all of these into an array with the format of `"type:data"`. Thanks for your help.

Comment: u can use xml parser in android

Comment: refer this http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html

Comment: @DIVA can you give me an example please ?

Comment: yes but i can give example of how to parse xml with showing my xml?

Comment: I need to get all the fields in my xml... I don't know but please do

Comment: Lets Discuss on chat

Comment: ok. Can you make one?

Comment: Have you solved your issue?

Comment: No, I haven't. I switched to JSON.

Comment: But if you have the solution I would gladly accept it.

Comment: @gedr I would recommend JSON. you can post it here. if you have any question in your JSON parsing

Answer (score 1):

You can use any one from the following:-
1) DOM Parser
2) Xml Pull Parser
3) Sax Parser.

You can use this link to parse a Xml. (http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-xml-parsing-tutorial/)